# Unable to save Json to apex generated class

Tags: apex, json

I am unable to save the below generated apex class. How to clear the error.

Error-

> Type name already in use: JSON2Apex.JSON2Apex at line 8 column 14

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Suggestions {
        public String suggestionType;
        public List<Address_Z> address;
    }

    public class JSON2Apex {
        public Address address;
        public Suggestions suggestions;
    }

    public class Address {
        public List<String> addressLines;
        public String cityTown;
        public String stateProvince;
        public String postalCode;
        public String countryCode;
        public String name;
        public Boolean residential;
        public String status;
    }

    public class Address_Z {
        public List<String> addressLines;
        public String cityTown;
        public String stateProvince;
        public String postalCode;
        public String name;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you cannot have a nested class with same name. So change name of JSON2Apex class at line number 8

Comment: You'll probably want to report that as a bug. I just verified that you can't have nested classes by the same name.